SQL Server 2016 -> 2022 upgrade causing error on OLE DB Driver connection
After the completion of an upgrade from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2022 on the DB Server, a client (front-end server) fails to connect to the DB.
The error message is :

Requested operation requires an OLE DB Session object, which is not supported by the current provider.

For more details :

The connection between the front-end and the DB SQL Server uses a TLS-encrypted link

The OLE DB Driver was initially of version 18.7.4

The connection string uses the following parameters :
Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxx;Encrypt=Yes;


No change on Data Source / DB Name / IDs was done with the upgrade.
The upgrade of the OLE DB Driver with the latest version (19.3.5) didn't solve the issue.

Test an OleDb connection outside the client program.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910364/quick-ways-to-test-ole-db-connection-string

I found this online:

The issue appears when the level of TLS on servers is increased

So it seems likely the upgrade allowed SQL Server to use (and require) a more recent TLS version than is currently available to your front-end server. So make sure your server is able to use at least TLS 1.2, and if not that's a BIG DEAL and you need to upgrade the server.

I did a new test by disabling encryption on the DB server and the client configuration string (non-encrypted connection)
It also gave the same error.
